# How can I log in to a hidden user?

Tags: login, login-screen, users

After some research, i found that you can make specific users hidden by using terminal and changing their ID to below 1000. I've done this for one of my users but now I can't login to that account. My login screen consists of User1 and Guest. There's no place for me to input the username and password of the hidden account.

I know it's possible to make the log in ask for the username and password every time but that's not what I'm looking for. Instead, I want User1 and Other to be in the login screen.
Is there any way of doing this?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with root permissions:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following line to the end of the file:

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

I'm not sure if you wanted to actually disable the guest account too. Judging from your question, it sounds like you might, so I'm including that too You would add this line to that same file to do that:

```
allow-guest=false
```

Then just save the file. I don't remember if you have to reboot the machine, or just log off for this to take affect.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways(edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`):

1. add `greeter-hide-users=true` (hide all users and give the option to write user and password)
2. add `greeter-show-manual-login=true` (open the menu to write user and password)

Comment: For me it made lightdm fail to load, giving the error "lightdm.conf keyfile does not start with a group"

Answer (score 1):

As some answers above, the cause is some users are blocked login with GUI, you can press Ctrl + Alt + F1 (or F2, ..) to change tty session, and login in via terminal.